# Whats The Proper Syntax When Dealing With Vector3?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, syntax

so I am making a button that saves and loads the players coordinates so that if a player goes 5 paces left on a plane, when I click save, leave, and then click load I will be at those 5 paces to the left. I recently finished off the code expect for one problem, **I don't know what's the proper syntax when dealing with vector3**.Heres [my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biVrn.png):

Feedback is always appreciated ;)

```
Vector3 lastPosx = Player.transform.position.x;
    Vector3 lastPosy = Player.transform.position.y;
    Vector3 lastPosz = Player.transform.position.z; //Vector3,int or float
    //Creates A Variable Called lastPosition Which is The Postion Of My Character
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("X", lastPosx);
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("Y", lastPosy);
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("Z", lastPosz);//SetFloat Or Setint?

}

public void Load()
{
    //Float ,int or vector3?
    float teleportx = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("X");
    float teleporty = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("Y");
    float teleportz = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("Z");//GetFloat Or Getint?
    Player.transform.position = new Vector3(teleportx, teleporty, teleportz);

}
```

Comment: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-ctor.html  `Vector3(float x, float y, float z);` Also, you don't have to take a screencap of your code. You can just copy and paste the relevant parts. It's usually a good idea to include any errors you get when you attempt to compile/run your code.

Comment: **Can You Please Be More Specfic I Don't Quite Understand What You Mean**

Comment: Instead of posting your code in the comments, please edit your question and put it in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Vector3` class stores all three components of a 3-D coordinate, so you don't need to do what you're doing with creating three separate `Vector3` objects.

But when saving out, you don't need to create the `Vector3` - you can just use the values directly from the transform, and then create a `Vector3` in the `Load()` method.

```
public void Save()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("X", Player.transform.position.x);
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Y", Player.transform.position.y);
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Z", Player.transform.position.z);
}

public void Load()
{
    // Vector3 has a constructor that takes 3 floats
    // Vector3(float x, float y, float z)
    Vector3 lastPosition = new Vector3(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("X"),
                                       PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Y"),
                                       PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Z"));
    Player.transform.position = lastPosition;
}
```